N-gon shading issue using Extrude
If someone is bored and would like to help me show how this topology is made without creating N-gons, it would be greatly appreciated. Asked a similar question yesterday and recieved a ton of help regarding the N-gon issue. However, countless tries from my part did not solve the shading issue while applying subdivision-modifier as I clearly don't understand how to create this without N-gons.
Ares with shading/clipping issues are marked with red. One side of the extrude has a slight angle to it.
The extruded part is beveled but the structure beneath has normal control loops.



Thank you and wish you all the best.

I could try to recreate this with quad topology, if I could only understand what all these multiple edges are for - they seem to be on flat faces, so no need for them to create some angles or anything... and then those random edges marked sharp inbetween...

Alright, thanks! I assume you mean the control edges for the larger structure from which I extruded along the Z-axis?
This is one issue I have, I don't understand if all those edges are necessary...

I have no idea how the model should look in detail, but from what I see I modeled something which might at least be transferable to your problem.
So I started off with a basic cube. A cube is all quad topology. Then I made loop cuts with Ctrl+R, the good thing is: the Loop Cut tool needs quads to work and it produces quads. I also moved some edges to get those slanted sides. So I finally made this shape, the extended parts created with the Inset tool I and extruded with E and it's all quads.

Of course adding a Subdivision Surface modifier now does not look too good, because the shape gets totally rounded.

One solution could be to add loop cuts as supporting edges close to all edges you want sharpened. The good thing again is, the Loop Cut tool produces quads when cutting quads. After finishing, my model looks like that:

It's all quad topology and the shading looks quite good, too. However, all those loop cuts introduce a lot of new vertices and are a destructive workflow, which makes it really hard if not almost impossible to change the shape of areas afterwards. As long as you are not certain that this is the final version you should try to avoid destructive workflows, since less geometry is always better to edit.
So therefore I would recommend another method: instead of cutting up the whole mesh, leave the geometry simple as it is. Then add a Bevel modifier to the object and place it before the Subdivision Surface modifier.

Now that does not look very nice. But here comes the trick: instead of using the default Limit Method > Angle in the Bevel modifier, set it to None. This will bevel all edges. Set the number of Segments to 1 or more depending on if you want a more rounded or sharper edge. But notice that the modifier has Clamp Overlap enabled by default, so it only bevels to the minimum amount that is possible on all edges to not overlap anything. (You can disable this option for rounder edges, but of course overlapping might cause problems then in some areas.)

The problem with setting the Limit Method to None is, when you also have curved shapes within this mesh (I've put a dome on its back for example), then beveling all edges might not look so good in areas where the surface is supposed to be smooth:

In this case, you can switch the Limit Method to Weight. This way, only edges that have a bevel weight assigned are affected by the modifier. In my example, I would select basically all edges except for the ones of the dome and its surrounding area (I only select the bottom edge where it connects to the floor) and in the sidepanel under Edge Data I set the Bevel Weight to 1.

By the way, the faces around the dome were n-gons as well because the round outline of the dome has more vertices. To get rid of shading errors in these areas, I selected the n-gons and pressed Ctrl+T to triangulate them (works in this case, but not always).

This result though (apart from the smoothed out dome probably) will most likely look more or less the same if you did not use any Subdivision Surface modifier at all, just added the Bevel modifier with a few more Segments and then shaded smooth. And to avoid weird shading, enable the Harden Normals option in the Bevel modifier.

Wow! I lift my hat for you Gordon.
Thank you for taking the time explaining and teaching this to me. Greatly appreciated! :)

Solved by extending the edges around the whole object.
Not sure if it's the optimal solution but it works fine.
Any ideas?


